# Pull street names from mysql to dropdown with php and display results on next page

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched all around stackoverflow, and only come across vague code on how to proceed. The closest was how to do multiple drop-downs based on one selection.

The overall concept is to pull street names from MySQL table with PHP into dropdown. On selection, display list of all people with that street name.

Comment: What is your existing code and what errors are you experiencing? In general, this is a combination of PHP & MySQL, with a bit of JavaScript/AJAX added to those two for the second part.

Comment: Have you heard of breaking a problem down into more individual, encapsulated tasks? Gees. Also, this is not a question.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the platform to post such queries or search for such solutions. Try Google Search instead.

Answer (score 2):

1. Build SQL query
2. Execute query
3. Parse results with PHP
4. Use a loop in PHP to output HTML select list